# Appending samples of different lengths to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to pull 3 samples from a large numpy array and put those samples together into a smaller numpy array. The samples are pulled if they meet certain conditions:

```
X_train_window = []
y_train_window = []
for i in nearby_locations[0]:
    X_train_window.append(X_train[np.where((X_train[:,0] == i[0]) & (X_train[:,1] == i[1]))[0]])
    y_train_window.append(y_train[np.where((X_train[:,0] == i[0]) & (X_train[:,1] == i[1]))[0]])
X_train_window = np.asarray(X_train_window)
y_train_window = np.asarray(y_train_window)
```

The samples all have different lengths, which seems to be complicating this process. As an example, the result from each iteration would result in something that looks like this:

```
sample_1 = np.array([[5.3, 6.5, 0],
            [5.3, 6.5, 2],
            [5.3, 6.5, 4]])
sample_2 = np.array([[5.32, 6.58, 0],
            [5.32, 6.58, 2],
            [5.32, 6.58, 4],
            [5.32, 6.58, 6]])
sample_3 = np.array([[5.42, 6.38, 0],
            [5.42, 6.38, 2],
            [5.42, 6.38, 4],
            [5.42, 6.38, 6],
            [5.42, 6.38, 8]])
```

I want `X_train_window` to be one big merged array, like this:

```
array([[5.3, 6.5, 0],
       [5.3, 6.5, 2],
       [5.3, 6.5, 4],
       [5.32, 6.58, 0],
       [5.32, 6.58, 2],
       [5.32, 6.58, 4],
       [5.32, 6.58, 6],
       [5.42, 6.38, 0],
       [5.42, 6.38, 2],
       [5.42, 6.38, 4],
       [5.42, 6.38, 6],
       [5.42, 6.38, 8]])
```

but this only works when the samples have the same length and then I can reshape it to the expected length:

```
X_train_window = np.reshape(X_train_window, (len(sample)*k, 3))
y_train_window = np.reshape(y_train_window, (len(sample)*k,))
```

where `len(sample)*k` is the expected length, which I can anticipate when the lengths are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

By design, a numpy array rows can only have one length.

The array you're trying to obtain can not be a numpy array. You can make such list of lists, but numpy will not allow it.

Maybe a solution would be to add a filler value to the rows that are too short. If all of your real values are positive you could use -1 as a filler.

Comment: You're wrong. It can be done by setting the dtype to object.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was overcomplicating this. It seems to be solved when I use the numpy concatenate function:

```
X_train_window = np.empty([1,3])
y_train_window = np.empty([1,])
for i in nearby_locations[0]:
    X_train_window = np.concatenate((X_train_window, X_train[np.where((X_train[:,0] == i[0]) & (X_train[:,1] == i[1]))[0]]))
    y_train_window = np.concatenate((y_train_window, y_train[np.where((X_train[:,0] == i[0]) & (X_train[:,1] == i[1]))[0]]))
X_train_window = np.delete(X_train_window, (0), axis=0)
y_train_window = np.delete(y_train_window, (0), axis=0)
```

I just have to drop the first row from the initialized empty array.

Comment: If you started with `np.empty([0,3])` you wouldn't need the `delete`.  But usually we discourage repeated `concatenate` in a loop.  List append is more efficient.  `np.concatenate([arr1, arr2, arr3], axis=0)`